# Flutter charts by Google library - only one axis is animating?

Tags: flutter, animation, dart, graph, charts

I am trying to code a tappable card which expands when the user taps on it. The card contains a graph and I would like for the opacity of various properties to be animated alongside the expand animation. I am using an AnimatedBuilder with the value of the animation controller being used to set the sized and opacity. I am successfully able to animate the y-axis, but for some reason the x-axis and x-axis label seen to act strangely and not animate properly. I think this may be a bug in the library but thought someone may be able to solve the issue. I am using charts_flutter: ^0.9.0 Thanks for any help or advice!

Use the following code to see the issue:

- The values on the y-axis animate in and out (transparent when small and visible when expanded)
- The values on the x-axis act weird and show up sometimes but the opacity never animates

If there is a better way of going about this please let me know - as there are a number of properties inside the graph and in parent widgets that will need to animate together - this is just a small example of the issue I am facing.

```
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(AnimatingGraphCard());
}

class AnimatingGraphCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AnimatingGraphCardState createState() => _AnimatingGraphCardState();
}

class _AnimatingGraphCardState extends State<AnimatingGraphCard>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _expanded = false;

  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      vsync: this,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      color: Colors.white,
      home: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        builder: (_, __) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => setState(() {
              _controller.animateTo(_expanded ? 0 : 1);
              _expanded = !_expanded;
            }),
            child: Center(
              child: Card(
                child: Container(
                  width: 300 + (_controller.value * 100),
                  height: 200 + (_controller.value * 150),
                  child: MyGraph(animation: _controller.value),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyGraph extends StatelessWidget {
  final double animation;

  MyGraph({
    this.animation,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    debugPrint("MarcinGraph");

    return TimeSeriesChart(
      _createDataSet(),
      defaultInteractions: false,
      domainAxis: DateTimeAxisSpec(
        renderSpec: GridlineRendererSpec(
          labelStyle: TextStyleSpec(
            color: ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.blue.withOpacity(animation)),
          ),
        ),
        showAxisLine: false,
      ),
      primaryMeasureAxis: NumericAxisSpec(
        renderSpec: GridlineRendererSpec(
          labelAnchor: TickLabelAnchor.centered,
          labelStyle: TextStyleSpec(
            color: ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.blue.withOpacity(animation)),
          ),
        ),
        showAxisLine: false,
      ),
      animate: false,
      dateTimeFactory: const LocalDateTimeFactory(),
    );
  }

  List<Series<Score, DateTime>> _createDataSet() {
    final chartData = [
      new Series<Score, DateTime>(
        id: 'Heart Rate',
        domainFn: (Score score, _) => score.date,
        measureFn: (Score score, _) => score.score,
        data: [
          Score(DateTime(2020, 2, 12), 4),
          Score(DateTime(2020, 2, 13), 8),
          Score(DateTime(2020, 2, 14), 7),
          Score(DateTime(2020, 2, 15), 12),
          Score(DateTime(2020, 2, 16), 6),
          Score(DateTime(2020, 2, 17), 9),
          Score(DateTime(2020, 2, 18), 11),
        ],
        colorFn: (_, __) => ColorUtil.fromDartColor(Colors.blue),
        strokeWidthPxFn: (_, __) => 1,
      )
    ];
    return chartData;
  }
}

class Score {
  final DateTime date;
  final int score;

  Score(this.date, this.score);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a key to the graphs parent widget has solved the issue.